# Is Chrome's device toolbar bugged?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chromium Version 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

div  {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 360px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try pasting this markup into notepad, save as a .html file and run it.
Go into Chrome's device toolbar and choose Lumia 950

2 things you'll notice:
- In the developer tool's box model view, you'll see the dimensions are 490x100
- In the device toolbar, you'll see that the screen is 360x640

So what is going on here?
So is 490 the new 180?

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with the issue, open up devtools on any page and switch to device mode.

Comment: but still, why does the div with a min-width of 360px takes up half the space of a 360px screen?

Comment: okay mate, I had difficulties understanding your issue. But figured it out now, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

In your `<head>`.

Devtools is not broken, it's just simulating the the actual pixels you get on some of the mobile phones.